# Why is this question getting no notice?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wrote [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1287961/strange-problems-installing-operating-systems-on-old-macbook-air) a few days ago. I spent a lot of time being very detailed and writing down everything that might be needed to solve my problem. In the first 5 minutes, it got 4 views, and since then it has only got a total of 18 views (as I am writing this). Aside from views, which may or may not be totally accurate, it has no votes, no flags, no comments or answers, no anything! By posting this question on Meta I am not trying to get people to view my post, I am just genuinely curious about why this question got inactive so quickly, something you don't see often on a Stack Exchange post.

Comment: There are generally certain times of day where the site doesn't experience as much traffic, so don't try to judge interest by the first few hours.  The question is generally pretty good.  One thing I noticed, though, is that the title doesn't really explain the problems, and people needed to read through a long section of detail and commentary to get to the actual question.  Some readers may lose interest without a framework or context of why and how everything is relevant; what problem does it all deal with.  (cont'd)

Comment: That detail is also what shows up on the main page, which could fail to attract readers.  I moved the questions section to the beginning so that people see the key info on the main page, and have context for reading the detail.  That may help a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem might be a lack of Mac users on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). While Macs are perfectly on topic here many fans of Apple devices may have migrated over to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and not check our site often. As a result your question may not get as many views as it would require knowledge of the vagaries of Mac hardware compared to PC hardware.

That said you should not cross-post questions, you can request it to be migrated or you can delete it yourself and repost there.

Comment: Thank you. This is probably the case. How can I request it to be migrated?

Comment: As it is not in the standard list of migration targets you can raise a flag on your question and give a custom reason asking for it to be migrated.